# How to prove all the derivatives vanishing at the end points

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let
$$f(x):=\cosh(2\sin x-\pi)-\cosh(2x-\pi) \text{ for } x\in [0, \pi]$$
Prove or disprove that all the derivatives at the boundary are zero, i.e.,
$$\forall k\in \mathbb N \hspace{0.5cm}  f^{(k)} (0)=f^{(k)} (\pi)=0.$$

**Comment:** What I know about this function is: $f$ is symmetric with center $\pi/2$. So proving $f^{(k)} (0)=0$ for all $k$ is sufficient. I want to prove such problem because I think that $\cosh(2x-\pi)$ is a "smooth approximation" of $\cosh(2\sin x-\pi)$ at the end points $0$ and $\pi$. Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, but the k-th derivative of the first term is implicit, which makes the evaluation difficult. I have try but I have no success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and second derivatives are $0$ at $x=0$.

The third derivative is
$$f'''(x)=8 \sinh (\pi -2 x)-6 \sin (2 x) \cosh (\pi -2 \sin (x))-$$ $$2 \cos (x) (2 \cos (2 x)+1)
   \sinh (\pi -2 \sin (x))$$
$$f'''(0)=2 \sinh (\pi )\neq 0$$

Comment: many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is analytic and nonconstant on $\mathbb C$, I think it would be impossible that $f^{(k)} (0)=0$ for all $k$. Here is a link: [If all derivatives are zero at a point, what does this imply?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397101/if-all-derivatives-are-zero-at-a-point-what-does-this-imply)

**Edit:** If we write $cosh(x) = \frac {e^x + e^{-x}} 2$ and $\sin(x) = \frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} 2$, we can see $f(x)$ can be also defined on $\mathbb C$. The derivative of a complex function $g$ is defined that $g'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac {g(z + \Delta z) - g(z)} {\Delta z}$. We can see derivative of $f$ on $\mathbb C$ exists.

However, differentiable complex functions (we also call them 'analytic' or 'holomorphic') have many special properties. For example, if an analytic function $g$ has derivatives of all orders zero at a point $z_0$, then $g$ must be constant at a neighborhood of $z_0$.

You can also check the second paragraph of Michael's anwser in the link.

Comment: I don't see why it is impossible, could you please make your argument more details? I the link, I see that Michael Burr gave a function which is $C^\infty$, so I think it is possible.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok I got the idea! Thank you so much for your explanation!